# Blocking launch of WPF Dialog from a different thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, modal-dialog

We want to create and launch a **modal dialog** box over the main window. This process is initiated from a different thread - for some reason. This different thread calls the execute method - and must be blocked until the dialog box closes. The question is - how? On this code the execute won't be blocked. The Join() call also does not work as expected.

```
public void Execute()
{
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
    // newWindowThread.Join();
}


private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
    this.ParameterDialog = new ParameterDialog();
    this.ParameterDialog.ShowDialog();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

Any idea how to implement this behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as i have tried, i do not believe you can create a new thread and run UI elements from it. All UI elements are to be on the main thread. If i am wrong i would love to know how. When i tried almost this exact same thing, i could not find a way. I had to use my logic in the alternate thread to basically have a Callback to the UI thread to open a dialog window.

Comment: Still don't know how to do that :(

Comment: You can communicate between threads using synchronisation context https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I . I think it's very likely what you're doing is a bad idea though.

Comment: Could alway use an AutoResetEvent. Have the thread wait on it, the dialog signal when it's done, so the thread can continue.

Comment: If you want the main thread to be blocked until the dialog box closes, then I do not think you need another thread. Just call ShowDialog from the main thread itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should shutdown the dispatcher when the dialog window is closed:

```
public void Execute()
{
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
    newWindowThread.Join();
}

private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
    this.ParameterDialog = new ParameterDialog();
    this.ParameterDialog.Closed += ParameterDialog_Closed;
    this.ParameterDialog.ShowDialog();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}

private void ParameterDialog_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ParameterDialog.Closed -= ParameterDialog_Closed;
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Comment: For some reason which are not quite clear the Dispatcher.Run() is not needed after the showdialog - but it is working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how your whole setup works, here is a quick example of how to utilize the Dispatcher to interact with the UI layer from a seperate thread. I used the examples from the microsoft wpf library [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples) as my starting point. I stripped out some of the code that is not applicable.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public delegate void NextPrimeDelegate();

    private bool _continueCalculating;

    private Action MyCallback = () => 
    {
        //****Carry out your Code (Execute) Here****
        var myPopup = new PopUp();
        myPopup.ShowDialog();
    };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartOrStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_continueCalculating)
        {
            _continueCalculating = false;
            startStopButton.Content = "Resume";
        }
        else
        {
            _continueCalculating = true;
            startStopButton.Content = "Stop";
            startStopButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new NextPrimeDelegate(MyCallback));
        }
    }
}
```

MyPopUp.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SingleThreadedApplication.PopUp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SingleThreadedApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PopUp" Height="200" Width="300">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                    Executed="CloseCommandHandler"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="My Popup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
</Grid>
```

Add this method to the PopUp.xaml.cs

```
private void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}
```

This hopefully can give you a starting point to interact with the UI layer via different Threads.